# Insert string variable value into the middle of another string variable's value in ksh

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

So I have a variable TRAILER which contains about 50 character. This variable is defined earlier in my shell session. As you can probably tell, it's a trailer to a file we'll be sending. I need to insert the record count of that file into the trailer. This record count is going to be 9 digits long (left padded with zeros if need be) and will start at index 2 of that string TRAILER. I want to retain all other characters in the TRAILER string just insert the RECORD_COUNT variable value into the TRAILER variable starting at index 2 (3rd character)

So the trailer variable is defined like this:

```
#Trailer details
TRAILER_RECORD_IDENTIFER="T"
LIFE_CYCLE="${LIFE_CYCLE_ENV}"
RECORD_COUNT="" #This will be calculated in the wrapper during the creation step
FILE_NUMBER="1111"
FILE_COUNT="1111"
CONTROL_TOTAL_1="               "
CONTROL_TOTAL_2="               "
CONTROL_TOTAL_3="               "
CONTROL_TOTAL_4="               "
CONTROL_TOTAL_5="               "
TRAILER="${TRAILER_RECORD_IDENTIFER}"\
"${LIFE_CYCLE}"\
"${RECORD_COUNT}"\
"${FILE_NUMBER}"\
"${FILE_COUNT}"\
"${CONTROL_TOTAL_1}"\
"${CONTROL_TOTAL_2}"\
"${CONTROL_TOTAL_3}"\
"${CONTROL_TOTAL_4}"\
"${CONTROL_TOTAL_5}"
```

Which then prints TRAILER as
    TRAILER="TD11111111......" that would be 75 blank spaces for all of the white characters defined by the CONTROL_TOTAL variables.

These variables ALL get defined in the beginning of the shell. REcord count is defined but left blank ebcause we won't know the specific file until later int he shell.

Later in the shell i know the file that i want to use, i get the record coun:

```
cat ${ADE_DATA_FL_PATH_TMP} | wc -l | read ADE_DATA_FL_PATH_TMP_REC_COUNT >> ${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
```

Now I want to take ADE_DATA_FL_PATH_TMP_REC_COUNT and write that value into the TRAILER variable starting at the 2nd index, padded with zero's to be 9 characters long. So if my record count is 2700 records the new trailer would look like...
    TRAILER="TD00000270011111111......"

Comment: To add to Cyrus comment, having an example of this TRAILER variable would help a lot.

Comment: edited my original post

Comment: Why don't you just wait until you *have* all the necessary data to define `TRAILER`?

Comment: When you want a `ksh` solution, please remove the `bash` tag.

Comment: Define your RECORD_COUNT variable with : typeset -Z9 RECORD_COUNT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use printf for padding.
I use `TD` as fixed first two characters, you can change this the way you want.

```
printf -v TRAILER "TD%.9d%s" "${ADE_DATA_FL_PATH_TMP_REC_COUNT}" "$(cut -c 12- <<< "${TRAILER}")"
```

Perhaps this is a good time switching to writing variable names in lowercase.